# Biopython Array Addition Error (Open for all)

Tags: python, numpy, biopython, scientific-computing, protein-database

Okay. Let me explain the things first. I have used a specific module named `Biopython` in this code. I am explaining the necessary details to solve the problem if you are not accustomed with the module.

The code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from Bio.PDB.PDBParser import PDBParser

import numpy as np

parser=PDBParser(PERMISSIVE=1)

structure_id="mode_7"
filename="mode_7.pdb"
structure=parser.get_structure(structure_id, filename)
model1=structure[0]
s=(124,3)
newc=np.zeros(s,dtype=np.float32)
coord=[]
#for chain1 in model1.get_list():
#   for residue1 in chain1.get_list():
#       ca1=residue1["CA"]
#       coord1=ca1.get_coord()
#       newc.append(coord1)
for i in range(0,29):
    model=structure[i]
    for chain in model.get_list():
        for residue in chain.get_list():
            ca=residue["CA"]
            coord.append(ca.get_coord())
    newc=np.add(newc,coord)

print newc

print "END"
```

PDB file is the protein data bank file. The file I'm working with can be downloaded from https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8oUhqYoEX6YVFJBTGlNZGNBdlk

If you remove the hashes from the first for loop, you'll find that `get_coord()` returns a `(124,3)` array with dtype `float32`. Likewise, the next for loop is supposed to return the same.

It gives out a strange error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./average.py", line 27, in <module>
    newc=np.add(newc,coord)
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (124,3) (248,3)
```

I am absolutely clueless how it manages to make a `248,3` array. I just want to add the array coord over itself. I tried with another modification of the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from Bio.PDB.PDBParser import PDBParser

import numpy as np

parser=PDBParser(PERMISSIVE=1)

structure_id="mode_7"
filename="mode_7.pdb"
structure=parser.get_structure(structure_id, filename)
model1=structure[0]
s=(124,3)
newc=np.zeros(s,dtype=np.float32)
coord=[]
newc2=[]
#for chain1 in model1.get_list():
#   for residue1 in chain1.get_list():
#       ca1=residue1["CA"]
#       coord1=ca1.get_coord()
#       newc.append(coord1)
for i in range(0,29):
    model=structure[i]
    for chain in model.get_list():
        for residue in chain.get_list():
            ca=residue["CA"]
            coord.append(ca.get_coord())
    newc2=np.add(newc,coord)

print newc

print "END"
```

It gives out the same error. Can you help???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you're doing, but it looks like you need to reset the `coords` list at the start of every iteration:

```
for i in range(0,29):
    coords = []
    model=structure[i]
    for chain in model.get_list():
        for residue in chain.get_list():
            ca=residue["CA"]
            coord.append(ca.get_coord())
    newc=np.add(newc,coord)
```

If you keep appending without clearing the list you add 124 items to `coords` at every iteration of the outer loop. The exception you see is likely raised during the second iteration.

Comment: should I initialize the array every time then?

Comment: I put the relevant line in my answer. `coords = []` at the beginning of the `for` loop.